# Store `local-set-key` in the configuration of emacs

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, key-bindings

For example, I use the command `local-set-key`  to set the key <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> for `flymake-goto-next-error` in `python-mode`.

Instead of writing an expression and wrapping it into `python-mode-hook`, is there a convenient way to store this keybinding directly? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-n") 'flymake-goto-next-error)
```

works in the current buffer's local **map**. It is correct when local **map** is **python-mode-map**.

Convenient minimum lenght command (without using **hook**)

```
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n") 'flymake-goto-next-error)
```

works when variable **python-mode-map** has been created.

Variable **python-mode-map** is created *dynamically* (in file python-mode.el) after call

```
(require 'python-mode)
```

If **python-mode** hasn't been loaded, command **define-key** can't directly use **python-mode-map**. Using hooks is for safety. Your emacs config should be reliable (it shouldn't depend on command's execution order if possible), and such wrapped (with hooks) commands prevent wrong situation: setting keybind in **mode-map** without setup **mode**.

Comment: Instead of requiring the python-mode, you could use eval-after-load:  `(eval-after-load 'python-mode '(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n") 'flymake-goto-next-error)))` To define the keys only when the mode is loaded.

Comment: @Rémi: It is unclear how this would improve anything over `python-mode-hook`, though.

Comment: The advantage of using `eval-after-load` instead of a mode hook is that it runs exactly once, rather than every time the mode is enabled in some buffer; but for inexpensive code like this, I don't think it matters which way you do it. Either way is better than forcibly `require`ing the library regardless of whether you're going to use it.

Comment: Another advantage of the after load code is when you want to test another binding for this key: the hook will reset the key every time you open a new file, the after-load won't.